# C++ - Hash Algorithm Code Returns Nothing

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I have come today to ask a question involving some code.

I have written a custom hashing algorithm in C++.
However the program runs without any errors but at the same time it prints nothing.

I am working on a Alt-Coin side project, even though I know it will never be worth anything with all the other Alt-Coins out there.
I decided I would write my own hashing algorithm, instead of using some other type of hash algorithm for my coin's block chain and other things needed.

I've been told in the past that I shouldn't use my own custom encryption or hashing, but I decided I would give it a try.

Can someone tell me why this is not working properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int dword;

struct
{
    dword count;
    dword recept;
    dword multiple = 13;
    dword divisible = 1.6;
    dword subhexvalue;
    std::vector<dword> endrecept;
} SMDH;

inline dword smdh(std::string data)
{
    for (SMDH.count; SMDH.count < data.length(); SMDH.count++)
    {
        SMDH.recept = SMDH.recept ^ (data[SMDH.count]) * SMDH.multiple / SMDH.divisible + SMDH.recept;
    }
    for (SMDH.count = data.length(); SMDH.count >= 0; --SMDH.count)
    {
        SMDH.subhexvalue = ((SMDH.recept >> (4 * SMDH.count)) % 16);
        if (SMDH.subhexvalue < 10) {SMDH.endrecept.push_back(SMDH.subhexvalue); }
        else { SMDH.endrecept.push_back((char)'A' + (SMDH.subhexvalue - 10)); }
    }
    for (SMDH.count = 0; SMDH.count < sizeof(SMDH.endrecept) / sizeof(SMDH.endrecept[0]); ++SMDH.count)
    {
        SMDH.recept = (SMDH.recept >> SMDH.endrecept[SMDH.count]); 
    }
    return SMDH.recept;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << smdh("testing");
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is suppose to be XORing every byte in the string, then multiplying it then dividing then adding itself. Then it's suppose to be converted to Hexadecimal.

I don't get any errors just a blank response.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being captain obvious, did you try to force flush the output?

Comment: The only things I'm trying to overwrite is the recept variable. That's why i made substitute variables. I don't know if that's what you were asking...

Comment: Oh wait, I think I didn't even modify the data argument... I hashed the recept variable not the data argument, I am going to try it again.

Comment: `sizeof` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: `sizeof(SMDH.endrecept) / sizeof(SMDH.endrecept[0]` makes no sense. Make it `SMDH.endrecept.size()`

Comment: `dword`? Are you explicitly trying to be non-portable?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl, No it's the other way around, that's why i made it a typedef so I don't have to use VS's version.

Comment: Making `smdh` depend on the last state of a global variable is not the greatest idea... and using global variable also not a good idea. For example, if you call the function twice in a row, the second time it would not start at 0...

Comment: Well, and in addition to be essentially useless, your `dword` type is also improperly used. How do you expect it to store a floating point value as in `dword divisible = 1.6`. Maybe, reading a few C++ books to learn better the language would be a good idea.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice I put a float in a unsigned int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop never finishes. `SMDH.count` being an unsigned type, `SMDH.count >= 0` is always true. Since the loop adds to the vector on every iteration, eventually the program runs out of memory, throws `bad_alloc` and terminates.